# versioning to prevent optimistic lock

Tags: oracle, jpa

just to follow the best practice, I have a good understanding of how and why to use `versioning` but is it a good practice to create a `version` column to prevent `optimistic locking` with the version number for every table, and what is its cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not giving enough context. I assume you refer to Hibernate versioning.
The version column is used by Hibernate not to prevent, but indeed to implement optimistic locking. From [hibernate reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html#d0e2251):

```
@Entity
public class Flight implements Serializable {
...
    @Version
    @Column(name="OPTLOCK")
    public Integer getVersion() { ... }
}
```

The column allows to have a version for each row in the table. Now, imagine you performed two reads of the same Flight entity (same row in the Flight table), using two concurrent threads (may be two separate web requests). Assume that both reads have an initial version of 1.

Now, whover persists first, will increment the version cell of the retrieved line, so that version will be 2.

Therefore, as soon as the second persist occurs, Hibernate is able to tell that there was a [lost update](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-a-lost-update-in-database-systems) since the second persist will also try to increment the version to 2, but the version is already 2 in the database (due to first commit)

The cost of this procedure is negligible, since the version is retrieved and written along with all the other fields of the entity.